# Old component got undefined after set other component to list in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-table

I got a bug that i struggle 1 week for this.
I have a react table with each row is each product in list[image]

When i change number or price, the last column will change price and set this price to list for send to back end

```
function CountTotalPrice({
  data,
  setListProductImport,
  listProductImport,
  setNewList,
}) {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState<any>()
  const handleSetPrice = () => {
    const list = listProductImport
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.productId == data.productId) {
        const totalPrice = new BigNumber(item.amount).multipliedBy(
          item.costPrice,
        )
        const discountPrice = new BigNumber(item.amount)
          .multipliedBy(item.costPrice)
          .multipliedBy(item.discount)
          .dividedBy(100)
        if (item.discount) {
          const afterPrice = totalPrice.minus(discountPrice)
          setPrice(afterPrice)
        } else {
          setPrice(totalPrice)
        }
      }
      return item
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSetPrice()
  }, [listProductImport])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (price) {
      const list = listProductImport
      const newList = list.map((item) => {
        if (item.productId === data.productId) {
          return { ...item, price: price.toFixed() }
        }
        return item
      })
      console.log("newList", newList)

      setNewList(newList)
    }
  }, [price])

  return (
    <div className="py-2 text-center text-white rounded-md cursor-pointer bg-successBtn">
      {new BigNumber(price).toFormat(0)} đ
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm using the `console.log("newList", newList)` and see the totalPrice at the last can add to list, but if i have more than 2 item, the old before will set to undefined. like this:
[image]

Any one can help me with this. I am very thank you.

Comment: My problem is the price of listProductImport is undefined, so each time it map, it will return undefine

Comment: How are you using that component in `react table`? Plus how does `listProductImport` look like? And what does `setNewList` do?